# Boost.Asio - Multiple buffers with custom buffer

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I'm writing a kind of tcp server. I'm using Boost.Asio, with [shared_const_buffer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp11/buffers/reference_counted.cpp).

Now I have to write multiple buffers. So I write like this:

```
std::vector<shared_const_buffer> bufs;
bufs.push_back(buf1);
bufs.push_back(buf2);
...
boost::asio::async_write(*pSock, bufs, [] { ... });
```

However, I can see an error.

> d:\boost_1_56_0\boost\asio\detail\consuming_buffers.hpp(175): error C2679: 이항 '=' : 오른쪽 피연산자로 'shared_const_buffer' 형식을 사용하는 연산자가 없거나 허용되는 변환이 없습니다.

Well, my Visual Studio is not English version >o< Here's my translation

> d:\boost_1_56_0\boost\asio\detail\consuming_buffers.hpp(175): error C2679: binary operator '=' : there's no operator or permissible conversion which use `shared_const_buffer` type as right-hand-side.

I'm not sure that my translation is correct, but I think you can get a point. Anyway, I saw `boost\asio\detail\consuming_buffers.hpp(175)` to figure out the problem.

```
if (!at_end_)
{
  first_ = *buffers_.begin(); // <-- here's error point
  ++begin_remainder_;
}
```

So I tried adding casting operator into `shared_const_buffer`, and it works magically.

Here's my [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

#include <boost/asio.hpp>

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

class shared_const_buffer
{
private:
    std::shared_ptr<std::vector<char> > m_pData;
    boost::asio::const_buffer m_buffer;

public:
    explicit shared_const_buffer(const std::vector<char> &data)
        : m_pData { std::make_shared<std::vector<char> >(data) }
        , m_buffer { boost::asio::buffer(*m_pData) }
    {

    }

    typedef boost::asio::const_buffer value_type;
    typedef const boost::asio::const_buffer *const_iterator;
    const boost::asio::const_buffer *begin() const { return &m_buffer; }
    const boost::asio::const_buffer *end() const { return &m_buffer + 1; }

    // it'll work if you uncomment this line.
    //operator const boost::asio::const_buffer &() const { return *begin(); }
};

void run_accept(boost::asio::io_service &iosrv, tcp::acceptor &acpt);

int main()
{
    boost::asio::io_service iosrv;

    tcp::acceptor acpt(iosrv, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), 12345));
    run_accept(iosrv, acpt);

    iosrv.run();
}

void run_accept(boost::asio::io_service &iosrv, tcp::acceptor &acpt)
{
    auto pSock = std::make_shared<tcp::socket>(iosrv);
    acpt.async_accept(*pSock,
        [&, pSock](const boost::system::error_code &ec) {
            run_accept(iosrv, acpt);

            std::vector<shared_const_buffer> bufs;
            bufs.push_back(shared_const_buffer({ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' }));
            bufs.push_back(shared_const_buffer({ 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h' }));

            boost::asio::async_write(*pSock, bufs,
                [pSock](const boost::system::error_code &ec, size_t size) {
                    pSock->close();
                });
        });
}
```

However, I can't know *why* it doesn't work. [According to documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/buffer.html#boost_asio.reference.buffer.buffers_and_scatter_gather_i_o),

> **Buffers and Scatter-Gather I/O**
>
> To read or write using multiple buffers (i.e. scatter-gather I/O), multiple buffer objects may be assigned into a container that supports the MutableBufferSequence (for read) or ConstBufferSequence (for write) concepts:

```
char d1[128];
std::vector<char> d2(128);
boost::array<char, 128> d3;

boost::array<mutable_buffer, 3> bufs1 = {
  boost::asio::buffer(d1),
  boost::asio::buffer(d2),
  boost::asio::buffer(d3) };
bytes_transferred = sock.receive(bufs1);

std::vector<const_buffer> bufs2;
bufs2.push_back(boost::asio::buffer(d1));
bufs2.push_back(boost::asio::buffer(d2));
bufs2.push_back(boost::asio::buffer(d3));
bytes_transferred = sock.send(bufs2);
```

Also [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp11/buffers/reference_counted.cpp) says it's enough with these 5 line to satisfy "ConstBufferSequence".

```
// Implement the ConstBufferSequence requirements.
typedef boost::asio::const_buffer value_type;
typedef const boost::asio::const_buffer* const_iterator;
const boost::asio::const_buffer* begin() const { return &buffer_; }
const boost::asio::const_buffer* end() const { return &buffer_ + 1; }
```

What did I miss? I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Update 3 and boost 1.56.0.

Comment: Can you tell me which line results in the mentioned error?

Comment: @LajosArpad error occurs in `first_ = *buffers_.begin();`. Compiler also noted `boost::asio::async_write(*pSock, bufs, ...`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The subtle detail is that `std::vector<shared_const_buffer>` is being passed to the `write()` operation, and thus it must support the [ConstBufferSequence](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ConstBufferSequence.html) concept.  While `shared_const_buffer` meets the type requirements for ConstBufferSequence, `std::vector<shared_const_buffer>` fails to meet the type requirements for ConstBufferSequence.  One of the requirements for ConstBufferSequence is that for type of `X`, `X::value_type` is a type that meets the type requirements of [ConvertibleToConstBuffer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ConvertibleToConstBuffer.html).  Basically, an instance of [`const_buffer`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/const_buffer.html) must be constructible from `X::value_type` and assignable from `X::value_type`:

```cpp
X::value_type a;
boost::asio::const_buffer u(a);
u = a;
```

In the case of `std::vector<shared_const_buffer>`, the `value_type` is `shared_const_buffer`, and `shared_const_buffer` can neither be used to construct `const_buffer` nor assigned to `const_buffer`.  Hence, the resulting compilation error.

Comment: What great timing. I had _just_ posted my answer. Can't not +1 now I suppose :)

Answer (score 4):

`async_write` takes a [`ConstBufferSequence`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ConstBufferSequence.html). According to the docs, the first requirement that this concept needs to satisfy is:

[image]

In your sample, `std::vector<shared_const_buffer>::value_type` evaluates to `shared_const_buffer`, which means it needs to model [`ConvertibleToConstBuffer`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ConvertibleToConstBuffer.html). By adding the conversion, you satisfy exactly that.

Comment: Hah, certainly great timing. (:

Comment: @sehe and Tanner: Voltaire said 'les beaux esprits se rencontrent' !   
Literaly translated as "great minds meet each other" ...

Comment: @John06 My take: "Great minds read the docs" + "Tanner monitors [tag:boost-asio]" + "sehe monitors [tag:boost-...]". The timing cannot be explained by the beauty of minds :)